# Postgres SQL gathering data from two tables using an id from a 3rd table

Tags: sql, postgresql, multiple-tables

I have 3 tables;

- idmaster
- data1
- data2

`idmaster` has every id. I need to count how many times each id exists in both data1 and data2 and output them seperate.

`id` comes from `idmaster`. Ideally would like to have all of them, even if no data exists, but thats not as important.
`data1` and `data2` do have id columns.

Example

| id | data1 cnt | data2 cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 104 | 20 |
| B | 12 | 4 |
| C | 0 | 0 |

I tried this, but it gives me some nonsense numbers, data1 and data2 had the exact same number which doesnt match up to my data.

```
SELECT idmaster.id, count(data1.*), count(data2.*) FROM idmaster, data1, data2
WHERE idmaster.id = public.data1.id 
AND idmaster.id = public.data2.id
GROUP BY idmaster.id
```

Results:

| id | data1 cnt | data2 cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 160 | 160 |
| B | 66 | 66 |
| C | 7 | 7 |

I'm expecting something like this:

Example

| id | data1 cnt | data2 cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 104 | 20 |
| B | 12 | 4 |
| C | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `left join` to find the counts of ids separately in data1, data2 tables, then join this two separate queries to get the desired output.

```
with data1_counts as
(
  select M.id, count(D1.id) data1_cnt from 
  idmaster M left join data1 D1
  on M.id=D1.id
  group by M.id
),
data2_counts as 
(
  select M.id, count(D2.id) data2_cnt from 
  idmaster M left join data2 D2
  on M.id=D2.id
  group by M.id
)

select dt1.id, dt1.data1_cnt, dt2.data2_cnt
from data1_counts dt1 join data2_counts dt2
on dt1.id=dt2.id
order by dt1.id
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/EyOxmwkD).

Answer (score 0):

You can use two "scalar subqueries" (line #2 and #3 below) to compute the count of related rows. For example:

```
select id,
  (select count(*) from data1 d where d.id = m.id) as data1_cnt,
  (select count(*) from data2 d where d.id = m.id) as data2_cnt
from idmaster m
```

Comment: This is similar to what I tried, but the query just runs. I've let it run for over 3 minutes before cancelling it.